# Json file display to html

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to display a json local file to a html file. Found something on the google, but it really give me headache
I got the following json file:

```js
{
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe - python  autotimer.py",
            "time_entries": [
                {
                    "days": 0,
                    "end_time": "2020-04-14 17:14:12",
                    "hours": 0,
                    "minutes": 0,
                    "seconds": 4,
                    "start_time": "2020-04-14 17:14:08"
                },
            ]
        },
```

and the following html file. My problem with this html file is the  part from the bottom, don't know if that is really good or not. I deteled te html part, cuz i doesn't let me post my question.

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (
        $.getJSON("activities.json", function (data) {
            var activities_data = '';
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                activities_data += '<tr>';
                activities_data += '<td>' + value.name + '</td>'
                activities_data += '<td>' + value.days + '</td>'
                activities_data += '<td>' + value.end_time + '</td>'
                activities_data += '<td>' + value.hours + '</td>'
                activities_data += '<td>' + value.minutes + '</td>'
                activities_data += '<td>' + value.seconds + '</td>'
                activities_data += '<td>' + value.start_time + '</td>'
                activities_data += '</tr>'
            });
            $('#activities_table').append(activities_data);
        });
));
</script>
```

What I'm doing wrong?
I'm a newbie to all of this.

Comment: `$.getJSON` and similar AJAX commands will only work in a server environment; if you open the HTML file directly in the browser you're in the `file:///` environment and it won't work. Get apache2 or some other web server solution and serve the files on `localhost`.

Comment: It looks like you want to access properties inside the "time_entries" key in your object. So, instead of value.days, you would use value.time_entries[0].days, value.time_entries[0].end_time, etc. Of course, this is assuming that you only care about the first item in time_entries .

Comment: It's on a web server and it still doesn't display my info..

Comment: Instead of `$.each(data,` you need to iterate through `$.each(data.activities,`. Then, you can append `value.name`,  `value.time_entries[0].days`, `value.time_entries[0].end_time` as td elements.

Comment: Tried everything you said, but nothing... changed instead of $.each(data, using $.each(data.activities, .. I really don't know, is there a place where i can put the entire code for you? Maybe i'm skiping something important in header, or maybe everything that is in my code is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this local file then first save this file with filename.json file type then import or require that file like import * as data from filename.json then use it with **data.default.activities[0].name**. or if this is global mean coming from somewhere else then parse that data first it will return object then use